# Zend Reader doesn't work, file is not readable

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hey does anyone have idea why Zend Reader don't want read file I need?

**FooController.php :**

```
$reader = new Zend\Config\Reader\Ini();
$data = $reader->fromFile("application.ini");
```

**Application.ini** is in `FooController` directory.

Reader returns error: - `File 'application.ini' doesn't exist or not readable`

but if I try

```
require_once('application.ini)
```

file is included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because you're not specifying the full path of you're file.
You could use this if the file is in the same directory

```
$reader = new Zend\Config\Reader\Ini();
$data   = $reader->fromFile(__DIR__."application.ini");
```

or this if the file is in a different directory

```
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH ."YOUR_PATH")
```

Comment: Ok file is loaded, but what if I want to load file from App/Config?

Comment: Not in module path

Comment: @bielu000 accept this answer if it solved your answer.

Comment: I have no enought reputation points, so I can't click "answer is usefull" ;/

Comment: @bielu000 You actually can accept it. Click on the correct sign it looks something like this ✓

Comment: -_-, sory, my bad ;)